# Hide app widget depending on API level

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created three app widgets with different sizes for pre Honecomb versions of Android and one resizable scrollable listview widget for Honeycomb and later.

Since the widgets offer the same functionality and the one targeted for Honeycomb and later is resizable I would like to remove the other versions of the widget on API level 12 or later. Is this possible somehow?

As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be any way to disable a widget from getting registered by the AppWidgetService if it can find the AppWidgetProviderInfo resource file. So it seems that I can only include widgets on later versions but not exclude versions defined in xml folders that targets earlier API versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it were a single app widget that had pre-HC or HC implementations, you could combine them into one `AppWidgetProvider` and use `res/xml-v11/` and `res/xml/` to have different metadata.

The only way I can think of to handle your scenario, though, is to mark some of the `AppWidgetProviders` as disabled in the manifest (`android:enabled="false"`), then enable and disable your providers on the first run of your app based on `android.os.Build.VERSION` using `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`, to give you the right set. Since on Android 3.1+, the user will need to launch one of your activities to be able to add the app widget, anyway, you at least have the entry point in which to apply this logic.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is working great. It would have been nicer if you could use the `android:enabled` attribute in `appwidget-provider` instead but this will have to do.. :)

Comment: @CommonsWare can you give some brief idea.

Comment: Why don't you just make an `xml` file with a boolean value in it.  In `res/values-v11/` (or whichever should have it excluded) set the boolean to false and in your `AndroidManifest`, reference the boolean for `android:enabled="@bool/enable_listview_appwidget"`?

Comment: @xbakesx: When I wrote this answer, I probably was thinking that your approach would only work in one direction. However, with *two* `bool` resources, it could work for this scenario. Have `@bool/honeycomb` and `@bool/not_honeycomb`, with appropriate values from `res/values/` and `res/values-v11/`, and use those in the `android:enabled` attribute.

Comment: @Harshid I added an answer with an example for you.

Answer (score 22):

The OP already got his solution, but for the rest of us, we can leverage `bool` values in xml and set them differently in different resource directories.

So your `AndroidManifest` looks something like this:

```
<receiver
  android:label="@string/app_widget_small"
  android:enabled="@bool/is_pre_api_11">

  <!-- App Widget Stuff Here -->

</receiver>
<receiver
  android:label="@string/app_widget_large"
  android:enabled="@bool/is_pre_api_11">

  <!-- App Widget Stuff Here -->

</receiver>
<receiver
  android:label="@string/app_widget_resizeable"
  android:enabled="@bool/is_post_api_11">

  <!-- App Widget Stuff Here -->

</receiver>
```

And in `/res/values/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_pre_api_11">true</bool>
    <bool name="is_post_api_11">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in `/res/values-v11/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_pre_api_11">false</bool>
    <bool name="is_post_api_11">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Now your API 10 and below will have two app widgets (small and large) and API 11 and higher will have the one resizeable app widget.

Comment: seems like you can use just one bool

Comment: @Alexey, yeah in this case you could just use one boolean, that was 4.5 years ago now, but I'm pretty sure I had other conditions around that leveraging the same tactic.  Good call though, in this simple case just one boolean suffices.