# Resizeable widget backwards compatibility

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to offer the user the following widget setup for the different Android versions:

- 2.3 to 3.0: 2 widgets, one is 1x1, the other is 2x2
- 3.1+: 1 resizeable widget only

i.e. *I would like to offer more widgets to the user on Gingerbread*, because we cannot resize them.

### Reason:

- *as a user of 3.1+*, I do not want to see many duplicated widget sizes. I want to see 1 widget, which I can resize
- *as a user of 2.3*, I cannot resize. I want to see 2 widgets, with different sizes.

---

### What I know:

- I can use `android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"` in my XML targetting current version, and that will be ignored on 2.3. This will not break the widget
- Or I can use XML folder targetting specific API levels e.g. `xml\` & `xml-v12`.

But the 2nd option only allows resources in `xml\` to be *replaced* if they are redeclared in `xml-v12\`.

**Is there a way to remove resources in later API versions, instead of replacing them?**

---

### Workaround:

1. Declare 2 widgets in the manifest, but disable one of them.
2. When the app is run for first time on an earlier device, enable the second widget.
3. As long as the user runs the app before trying to install widgets, the effect is perfect.

(Note: as per @CommonsWare it is better to enable both widgets by default, and disable the one on the first run of the app on 3.1+)

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to: [Hide app widget depending on API level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680449/hide-app-widget-depending-on-api-level) (which I was unable to find when I JGFI...)

Below a summary of the answers provided, and which I think is best.

---

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683212/383414), by @CommonsWare, is basically to use the workaround I described above. One enhancement he suggests is to enable both on pre-3.1, and only disable when the app runs and detects 3.1+.

This is because 3.1 requires an `Activity` to be run before a user can add a widget. 3.0 has no such requirement. Doing it this way means that the pre-3.1 user always sees both widgets, while the 3.1+ user cannot see both.

---

**[A better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305982/383414)**, imho, was provided by @xbakesx.

His suggestion is to define boolean resources that are used to enable or disable the widgets in XML:

In `/res/values/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_pre_api_11">true</bool>
    <bool name="is_post_api_11">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in `/res/values-v11/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_pre_api_11">false</bool>
    <bool name="is_post_api_11">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Enable the appropriate widget in the `AndroidManifest.xml` by using these defined boolean resources:

```
<receiver
  android:label="@string/app_widget_resizeable"
  android:enabled="@bool/is_post_api_11">

  <!-- App Widget Stuff Here -->

</receiver>
```